# Android DialogFragmant layout not show all layout elements

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to call a dialog fragment from an FragmanActivity.
My dialog fragment include two edittext view and two buttons.

I read the android developer userguide but I can not resolve my problem.
([Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions))
My problem is: the DialogFragment window appears like only a small window.

My Dialog XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="790dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/ePostionDate"
   android:inputType="date"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/lblDate"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/eWaterPosition"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   android:hint="@string/lblWaterPostion"
   android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddWaterposition"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblBtnFixData"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelWaterposition"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblBtnCancel"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Part of my FragmentActivity where I try to call the DialogFragment:

```
        DialogFragment wpDialog = new WaterPositionEditActivity(getApplicationContext());
    wpDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "waterPositionSetter");
```

Finally my DialogFragment class:

```
enter code here
```

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class WaterPositionEditActivity extends DialogFragment {

```
private Context context;

public WaterPositionEditActivity(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.water_position, container, false);
}
```

}

I create my app for Android 2.2 but I want it could run on Android4 or upper.

The very small window look like this:
[image: part of the screenshot]

As you can see on the img only one edittext field show but there are another editview and two buttons. So this small window should bi bigger than now and show all layout elements!

Anyone can help what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I use RelativeLayout I forgot to add in  XML layout for the elements the right position.
When I add the right position for the elements the Dialog wondow appear as want.